# How to avoid L1 and L2 interference if learning an L3?

Tags: l2-acquisition, interference

Anyone got any ideas. I primarily speak English, but I know Japanese and French equally well but not as well as English, so they both become muddled when I try to speak either..

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. In order to help people understand your question, could you edit your question to explain what your L1, L2 and L3 are? I am assuming L1 (i.e. native language) is English, L2 is Japanese and L3 is French. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to train your brain to see French and Japanese as two different languages. After saying a sentence in French, immediately say it in Japanese also (and vice versa). This worked for me for Spanish and Italian. When talking to someone in Italian, I would repeat the Spanish equivalent of every sentence in my head immediately after saying it in Italian